# Cannot read the data in Asia/Calcutta timezone from Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timezone, sequelize.js

I am using Postgres for my database, and Sequelize as my ORM. My code works, but the only problem which I see here is, I cannot read the data in the `Asia/Kolkata` timezone. Sequelize shows me `UTC` time every time I try fetching the data in to that format.

I have tried many things, but same UTC timezone data. In my database, the data is stored in this format, that IST only:

```
|       starttime     |       endtime       |
| 2020-10-07 10:30:00 | 2020-10-07 11:30:00 |
```

And in Sequelize output, it gives me this:

```json
{
  "startTime": "2020-10-07T05:00:00.000Z",
  "endTime": "2020-10-07T06:00:00.000Z"
}
```

**1.** What I have tried is configuring my Sequelize database file like this:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', 'username', 'pwd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: { 
        useUTC: false,
        dateStrings: true,
        typeCast: (field, next) => { // for reading from database
            if (field.type === 'DATETIME') {
                return field.string()
            }
            return next()
        }
    },
    timezone: '+05:30' // for writing the output
});
```

**2.** I have also, tried this

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', 'username', 'pwd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: { 
        useUTC: false,
        timezone: '+05:30'
    },
    timezone: '+05:30'
});
```

**3.** Tried doing this as well

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', 'username', 'pwd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: { 
        useUTC: false,
        timezone: 'Asia/Calcutta' // also tried for Asia/Kolkata
    },
    timezone: 'Asia/Calcutta' 
});
```

Now with all my efforts, I still get the time in UTC timezone. I have tried getting the output in `Incognito mode`, for checking if there is any caching on the browser. No changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem, and that was `reading the data from the already existing data in the table`.

**More aptly:** I was trying to read the data which I stored in the database already, and not from the `Sequelize`. It was always showing me the data in the `UTC` format.

I tried creating/inserting one data using `Sequelize ORM` **with the above configuration in my `sequelize-db.js` file** and boom, the result was in `Asia/Kolkata` or `Asia/Calcutta` format. Although, I have used this configuration which was more apt for me:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', 'username', 'pwd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: { 
        useUTC: false,
        timezone: '+05:30' // for reading the data
    },
    timezone: '+05:30' // for writing the data
});
```

**Takeaway:** Always use the `Sequelize` for complete operation to see the things working :)